# How Can I instantiate a class template without a cast

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to run the first instantiation instead of the second, but the compiler takes the arguments as integers and returns errors.

Note that the use of optional is to allow the object to receive a boost::none (C++ version of python's None).

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

template<class T>
struct Point
{
    explicit Point(T x, T y): x (x), y (y){}
    T x;
    T y;
};

typedef boost::optional<int128_t> oint128_t;
int main(){
    // Point<oint128_t> P(90, 5); // this fails
    Point<oint128_t> Q((oint128_t) 91, (oint128_t) 31); // this works
}
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the template, it's because converting `90` to `oint128_t` requires two implicit conversions, one to `int128_t` and another to `oint128_t`. C++ only allows a single implicit conversion. You need some sort of cast to avoid that

Comment: I wonder what kind of `Point` has optional `x` coordinate. There would be some interesting mathematical implications of that.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen The reason I use optional is to allow it to receive a boost::none (C++ version of python's None), Is there a way around this?

Comment: My comment isn't really related to your problem. Or well, it could be, if you decided to not use `boost::optional` (which could solve your issue). I just can't imagine what does it mean for `Point` to have `boost::none` as one (or both) of its coordinates. What does it mean that point is at `(none, 5)` coordinate? Is it at `(0, 5)`? Is it in one-dimensional space only? Can I draw a line segment between `(none, 5)` and `(4, 5)`?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I wanted to use elliptic curve cryptography, and represent the point at infinity as (none, none), I am sure I could use OpenSSL libs, i am doing it this way for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always put the explicit casts inside of the `Point` constructor.

```
template<typename S>
explicit Point(S x, S y): x(T(x)), y(T(y)) {}
```

But I suspect that doing so will introduce more confusing type errors in the long run. My recommendation is to explicitly call the `boost::optional` constructor like you're supposed to. `T` is not meant to be an instance of `boost::optional<T>`. The cast you're invoking is actually calling a converting constructor and making a new object; you're just making it look like a conversion is taking place.